# Render new view on successful log in swift/swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am working on an ios app and i have had some trouble changing views when the user enters the correct username and password. I have built text fields for username and password and a button that sends the data to the api and checks if its correct. However, If the user enters correct credentials, I want the view to change to show the homepage. What is a good way to do this in swiftui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NavigationView` and `NavigationLink` if you want to navigate with buttons. For your use case, I would use if-statements.
Here an example:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var showingHomeView = false
    var body: some View {
        // If the second view isn't displayed, show the first view.
        if !showingHomeView {
            Button("Go to home") {
                showingHomeView = true
            }
        } else {
            // The home view should be displayed.
            Text("Home")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for responding late. Thanks for your answer it helped me a lot.